# Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http:// instead of https://

Tags: iis, httprequest

I'm using IIS to host my webapp. In Bindings, only HTTPS on port 443 defined. But when I check the logs, it still connect to HTTP. Is it correct?

Ex: the scheme is not HTTPS

> INFO  2021-05-20 15:57:56,645 [10   ]
> soft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost - Request starting HTTP/1.1
> GET
> http://10.86.202.211:41/fonts/Poppins/poppins-v5-devanagari_latin-ext_latin-300.woff2

Comment: What's the hosting model you used? If out-of-process hosting is used, then that log entry is perfectly normal, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/out-of-process-hosting?view=aspnetcore-5.0 as IIS talks to Kestrel in HTTP.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is correct. The hosting model is Out-of-process

Comment: Did Lex's comment solve your problem?

Comment: @samwu: ah, yes